# R - how to sum each columns from df

Tags: r

I have this df

```
df <- read.table(text="
   id     month  gas  tickets
   1      1      13   14
   2      1      12   1
   1      2      4    5
   3      1      5    7
   1      3      0    9
", header=TRUE)
```

What I like to do is calculate sum of gas, tickets (and another 50+ rows in my real df) for each month. Usually I would do something like

```
result <-
 df %>%
 group_by(month) %>%
 summarise(
   gas = sum(gas),
   tickets = sum(tickets)
 ) %>%
 ungroup()
```

But since I have really lot of columns in my dataframe, I don´t want to repeat myself with creating sum function for each column. I´m wondering if is possible to create some more elegant - function or something that will create sum of each column except id and month with grouped month column.

Comment: did you look at `summarise_at()` and `summarise_if()`

Comment: In base R `aggregate(.~ month, df[-1], sum)` perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `summarise_at()` to ignore `id` and sum the rest:

```
df %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(-id), list(sum = ~sum))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  month gas_sum tickets_sum
  <int>   <int>       <int>
1     1      30          22
2     2       4           5
3     3       0           9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aggregate` as markus recommends in the comments. If you want to stick to the tidyverse you could try something like this:

```r
df %>% 
    select(-id) %>% 
    group_by(month) %>% 
    summarise_if(is.numeric, sum)

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  month   gas tickets
  <fct> <int>   <int>
1 1        30      22
2 2         4       5
3 3         0       9
```